# Use of alias in JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, jpa

I've got a problem with `JPA Criteria Query`, in particular with aliases.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
Root<Evento> root = query.from(Evento.class);
Join<Evento, DataEvento> dataNode = root.join(Evento_.date);
query.where(pred).multiselect(dataNode.get(DataEvento_.evento), builder.least(dataNode.get(DataEvento_.dataDa)).alias("minData")).groupBy(dataNode.get(DataEvento_.eventoId));
return query.orderBy(builder.desc(dataNode.get(DataEvento_.dataDa).get("minData")));
```

I want to perform this query:

```
select MIN(de.data_da) as minData, de.id_evento from exlt_data_evento de inner join exlt_evento e on de.id_evento = e.id group by de.id_evento order by minData
```

The result is the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.dataDa] of basic type
```

In order by condition I need to get "minData", which is the alias created in the select condition.

Comment: did you check `dataDa` for null value?

Comment: Without orderBy condition my code works correctly. I cannot get selection by alias before query results generation. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: put `order by de.data_da` instead of minData

Comment: Reasonably, in this way my query produces the following error: "ERROR: column "date6_data_da" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

Comment: why are you trying to get field "minData" of "dataDa" ? and indeed what type is "dataDa"? because your post provides no information for people to comment on WHY you get that

Comment: An Event (Evento) can occur on different temporal intervals (DataEvento). Each interval starts on DataDa. I need a query that returns all the events that satisfy predicate "pred" ordered by the date on which they start (first date of the first interval).